# How to read an ascii file with json content: ValueError

Tags: python, json

I try to read this ascii file with this `json content` with the following function:

```
{ "directory": { "name": "/wiki", "files": { "file": [ { "name": "/wiki/a.txt", "digest": "97d37a2ff85fbe35e1bf8ad38934d8fb518a6a3fbeb9b0b9305ce98e992f9dd2 " },
    { "name": "/wiki/d.txt", "digest": "ef91ee1257c3faa49f86f343cfec66010e5810e99db9f42e88774f90cd5b95d9 " },] } } }


def readJsonFile(path):
    with open(path) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)

    return json_data
```

I get this `error` of no JSON object could be decoded:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I tried with `json.loads` and I get the error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Am I using the right function?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Check it at http://jsonlint.com/ which will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not a valid json (It has a trailing `,`).

But it's a valid python literal; you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
import ast

def readJsonFile(path):
    with open(path) as json_file:
        return ast.literal_eval(json_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is wrong, as validated by [jsonint](http://jsonlint.com/):

[image]